# How to render application.html.erb in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing

How can I render the `application.html.erb` view in a rails app?

I've tried adding a method to the `application_controller.rb` controller:

```
def amethod
end
```

And then updating the `routes.rb` file:

```
get '/', to: 'application#amethod'
```

to no avail. I get this error message:

**Missing template application/amethod with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/peterward/Directory/mini-project/app/views"**

It's looking for the `html.erb` view in the `app/views` directory instead of the `app/views/layouts` directory.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 3):

Rails is looking for a file named `views/amethod.html.erb`, the layout that you're using `application.html.erb` is not meant to hold the view for your controller action. The layout will yield to the controller action named view.

I suggest you read [Rail's render and layout guide.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

The quickest solution to solving your error would be to create a blank file: `app/views/amethod.html.erb`

However, this does not really address your problem, because I doubt you really just want to render a layout.